# Using a dylib in xcode

Tags: xcode, opengl, dylib

So, I'm trying to add this  library in an xcode project.
http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/sw/libdrawtext/

I used homebrew to install the library. It's now in /usr/local/Cellar/libdrawtext/

But, even after adding the dylib that is created in /usr/local/Cellar/libdrawtext/0.1/

I checked, and there's even an alias in the usr/local/bin folder.

But for the life of me, I can't seem to be able to include "drawtext.h" in my project.

The sample code [here](http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/hg/libdrawtext/file/d8c3ce3fa588/examples/simple/simple.c) has no indication of how to do this.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: Is the file in `/usr/local/include` or a subfolder? That's where homebrew usually adds header files.

Comment: Yup. Still won't work.

Comment: What's the error message when you try to `#include <drawtext.h>`?

Comment: Simple "drawtext.h file not found.

Comment: Ok, have you checked the "header search paths" in the project settings? It will also be a good idea to check the "library search paths" too.

Comment: I've added usr/local/include to the header search paths and /usr/local/Cellar/libdrawtext/0.1/lib to the library search paths.

Comment: @usm could you do me a favor and try to run the sample code on the website on your own? See if it works?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't think of anything else. However, I'd suggest using `/usr/local/lib` for the library search path so you can seamlessly upgrade to new versions when Homebrew updates. (Although if you want to stick to a particular version, make sure both headers and libs are pointing to the same one, to save headaches in the future).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Not sure exactly how, but I followed this tutorial http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/freetype/

After adding libdrawtext(from the homebrew installation), I also added the source of the library to my project. Works like a charm, though this is a VERY dirty solution.

I'll wait 24 hours, and if there're any better answers, I'll mark them correct.